# Psycopg2 insert statement with lists

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I was going through this documentation for psycopg2: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html
Following that documentation, which of these insert statements would be considered correct?

1. `cur.execute ('INSERT INTO tb VALUES (%s, %s)', row[0:2])`
2. `cur.execute ('INSERT INTO tb VALUES (%s, %s)', (row[0:2]) )`

where "row" is list of say 5 elements, and "tb" is a table containing 2 columns.

Comment: ...which one works when you try it?

Comment: They both works just fine. As @bernie pointed out I'm missing a comma in the second example so it isn't a tuple like I intended. I meant to ask which is the "correct" usage in terms of security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are effectively the same thing because simply putting parentheses around something doesn't make it a tuple; you would additionally need a trailing comma e.g.: `(row[0:2],)`

```
In [1]: row = [1,2,3]                                                             

In [2]: row[0:2]                                                                  
Out[2]: [1, 2]

In [3]: (row[0:2])                                                                
Out[3]: [1, 2]

In [4]: (row[0:2],)                                                               
Out[4]: ([1, 2],)
```

But to answer the question I think you meant to ask: according to [the DB-API's documentation for `.execute()`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15) the first alternative is correct: "Parameters may be provided as *sequence* or mapping..."

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO tb VALUES (%s, %s);', row[0:2])
```

In other words, you provide a sequence (a list in this case); and *not* a sequence of a sequence: a tuple of a list which, once again, would've looked like this: `(row[0:2],)`; note the trailing comma.

Comment: Makes sense. You're right, I missed the trailing comma. Thank you for your response! I wasn't sure  if providing a sublist instead of an entire list would make a difference.

Comment: You're welcome! A sublist is still a list so it's still ok. Happy coding to you.